# To find which events have been fired

Tags: magento

How one can check the list of all the fired events in Magento during a http request?
Also, there so many of them how can we check if that event has already been declared before or not.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mage::dispatchEvent() fires 2 profiler calls. So you can enable magento profiling and it will show you all dispatched events.

Also you can look at [Developer Helper](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer-helper-1724.html) extension to get list of all defined in config.xml observers.

Comment: I thought the same thing about the profiles for a while — but if the event firing doesn't trigger the profiler's time threshold, the items won't show up.